# jQuery - change doesn't fire when using bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, twitter-bootstrap

I have a calculator that's using Bootstrap on my selects along with this extension : http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/

I have different texts in the options, but the value can be the same as it represent the price of the selected item.

```
<select>
  <option value="0">Red</option>
  <option value="0.23">Green</option>
  <option value="0.23">Blue</option>
</select>
```

My problem is that jQuery doesn't fire the change event, when the value is the same. It works fine if the values differs. I thought I could make my own eventlistener, testing the textstring, but how do I do that? Or does anyone have a better idea?

Comment: If no change, why change handler should be fired? But you could try to use click instead/maybe

Comment: The click can't be used, because it's not the actually select i'm clicking. When I should make event on the ul created by Bootstrap.

Comment: So, if you click on other element, is this element has a click handler attached? If yes, just trigger inside it the select change event. If you post a jsfiddle to reproduce your issue, i'm sure a quite simple workaround can be find

Comment: I have created an example as you requested: http://jsfiddle.net/DjFHS/

Comment: As you can see, the event fires fine if I change between the first value 0 and one of the other, but if I change the between to who has the same value it doesn't fire. I could see through the Bootstrap lib and find the function that creates the selection on the selectbox, but I would prefer something easier.

Comment: Ok, i'll check and will let you know

Comment: See if it is working for you: http://jsfiddle.net/DjFHS/1/

Comment: It works! Thanks, I have made a small adjustment because I had more than one select who used the calculate-sum class, so I gave it, its own class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A work around you could use is to go with data attributes. Change your select to something like the below

```
<select>
  <option data-value="0" value='Red'>Red</option>
  <option data-value="0.23" value='Green'>Green</option>
  <option data-value="0.23" value='Blue'>Blue</option>
</select>
```

Then bind to change

```
$('select').on('change', function(){
    var val = $(this).data('value');
});
```

This way, the change event is triggered, you just need to get the value via the data attribute.

Comment: I already have this eventhandler set up and the problem is, that it will not fire when the value is the same.

Comment: And that's what I have changed. The value is not the same in this example. I take the value from the data attribute. The value attribute contains the name of your item so that the event triggers. It's a workaround. This will work.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I didn't look properly. You're right, this will work :)

Answer (score 0):

You could bind to the 'blur' event to check the value of the select when it loses focus (which would happen if they click it - to give it focus - then subsequently click else where (or tab in, and tab away) ).

Comment: I don't think it sets focus on the selectbox, it's just changed via javascript. Maybe there is no easy way. I could make an extension to Bootstrap, which handles the events...

Comment: Can we clarify what you want? 
The user clicks a select box, and selects the current selection - so there's no change. But you'd still like your callback hit, right?
If that's the case, blur will work. Otherwise you can consider binding your event to a timeout that's started when the user clicks on the select box